# Isolating re-used controller scopes with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently working on a project where I use a primary navigation to open tabs which lazy-load templates.

**EDIT: to clarify, the number of tabs can vary on a user basis, so I cannot do this hard coded.**

My way to try and accomplish this is by using a Tabs-controller with headers and the tab-items themselves:

```
    <section class="tabs" ng-controller="Tabs">
        <div class="tabs__header">
            <div class="tabs__header__item is-hidden" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-item="{{tab.item}}" ng-if="!tab.header">
                <a class="tabs__header__item__text" ng-href="#/{{tab.item}}" ng-click="tabClicked($event)" data-item="{{tab.item}}">{{tab.name}}</a>
                <a href="#" class="tab-close">x</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs__container">
            <div class="tabs__container__tab is-hidden" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" id="tab-{{ tab.item }}" ng-if="!tab.header" ng-controller="Tab" ng-include src="template.url"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the controllers would look like this:

Tabs.js:

```
function Tabs(scope, root) {

root.$on('/general/page/initdata', function(e, data) {
    //set default elements
    scope.tabs = data['nav-primary'];

    //open dashboard

});

root.$on('/nav/primary/open', function(e, itemName) {
    root.$emit('/tabs/activate', itemName);
    _setActiveTab(itemName);
});

scope.tabClicked = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    _setActiveTab(name);
};

function _setActiveTab(itemName) {
    var collection = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__header__item.js-is-active, .tabs__container__tab.js-is-active');
    angular.element(collection).removeClass('js-is-active');

    collection = document.querySelectorAll('#tab-'+itemName+', .tabs__header__item[data-item="'+itemName+'"]');
    angular.element(collection).addClass('js-is-active').removeClass('is-hidden');
}

};

Tabs.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
```

Tab.js

```
function Tab(scope, root) {

var loaded = false;

root.$on('/tabs/activate', function(e, itemName){
    if(scope.tab.item === itemName && !loaded) {
        loaded = true;
        scope.template = {url: '/frontend/templates/'+itemName+'.html'};
    }
});

};
Tab.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
```

Now, the problem is that template.url is modified for *each* tab whereas I only want to modify it for one tab. It turns out scope is shared between the various Tab-instances. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem wasn't with AngularJS. I had simply made an error with my js-is-active class, causing the wrong tab to be displayed.